# How to disable minimizing ios simulator on outside click in android studio?

Tags: flutter, simulator

I am learning flutter. I created flutter app and successfully installed in android and IOS simulator, I have a problem using ios simulator, when i click outside the simulator it get minimized. I want to disable it or want to open in android studio's window screen, is it possible or how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Click on your simulator, Go to the windows tab and check "Stay On Top".